# Full Outer Join Not Working - Need to return all dates regardless of null activity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, outer-join

I need to return a row for every date (DATES table) in the month regardless of whether or not there is an activity (tTimesheets table)

Built this query in the designer, I am far from well versed but am trying to make this work :)

From my googling, I believe either the WHERE clause is messing with my FULL OUTER JOIN. It looks like a derived table might be the solution? Or maybe need to bring some of the conditions into the joins rather than the WHERE clause.

I have read this [BLOG](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql/) on derived tables but just cant figure it out

Again appreciate the help!

```
SELECT tProjects.ProjectName,
       tProjects.ProjectID,
       Dates.Date,
       Dates.MonthNameYear,
       tUsers.id,
       tUsers.Name,
       sum(tTimesheets.ActivityTime) as Time,
       tExpenses.ExpenseID,
       tClients.ClientName
FROM tClients
    INNER JOIN tProjects
        INNER JOIN tTimesheets
            ON tProjects.ProjectID = tTimesheets.ProjectID
        INNER JOIN tUsers
            ON tTimesheets.CreatedBy = tUsers.id
        ON tClients.ClientID = tProjects.ClientID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tExpenses
        INNER JOIN tExpenseType
            ON tExpenses.CategoryId = tExpenseType.Id
        ON tTimesheets.CreatedBy = tExpenses.CreatedBy
           AND CAST(tTimesheets.ActivityDate AS date) = CAST(tExpenses.ExpenseDate AS DateTime)
           AND tTimesheets.ProjectID = tExpenses.ProjectID
    FULL OUTER JOIN Dates
        ON CAST(tTimesheets.ActivityDate AS date) = CAST(Dates.Date AS date)
   
WHERE        
(tProjects.ProjectName in (@parmProjects) OR tProjects.ProjectName is null)
AND
(Dates.MonthNameYear in (@parmDate) OR Dates.MonthNameYear is null)
AND
(tUsers.Name in (@parmUser) OR tUsers.Name is null)

GROUP BY 
         tUsers.Name,
         tUsers.id,
         Dates.Date,
         Dates.MonthNameYear,
         tProjects.ProjectName,
         tProjects.ProjectID,
         tExpenses.ExpenseID,
         tClients.ClientName

 ORDER BY Dates.Date
```

Comment: Move `Dates` to the top `FROM Dates` then `LEFT JOIN` everything else, and put all the `WHERE` conditions in the `ON` clauses

Comment: FYI, `in (@parmProjects)` is unlikely to do what you think it does.

Comment: or leave dates where it is and make it a right join.  in essence including all clients, but only if they have projects and timesheets. and their related expenses; but only if they have an expense type.  For all  the preceding, include all dates from dates and the associated timesheets where present.  Most people don't' like mixing left/right joins as it's easier to read.  and the flow of left joins from greatest rows to lest is usually preferred from a maintenance standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need a `FULL JOIN` here. You just need to start with `Dates` and `LEFT JOIN` everything else.**

All the `WHERE` conditions relating to those other tables need to then go in the `ON` clauses.

Further notes:

- `CAST(... AS date)` is inefficient when used as a join or filter condition. It's better to use a date interval range. And if you have a `Date` table, it should just be declared as `date` data-type anyway. I haven't changed it as I don't know your data.
- `d.MonthNameYear in (@parmDate) OR d.MonthNameYear is null` is somewhat suspect: why would `MonthNameYear` be null on a dates table. And `in (@parmDate)` is strange: is it supposed to match a list? If so, that is not going to work.
- Furthermore, using `OR` like that is probably going to cause performance issues
- Use short and meaningful table aliases, it makes the query more readable

```sql
SELECT p.ProjectName,
       p.ProjectID,
       d.Date,
       d.MonthNameYear,
       u.id,
       u.Name,
       sum(ts.ActivityTime) as Time,
       e.ExpenseID,
       c.ClientName
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN
   (tClients c
    INNER JOIN tProjects p
        ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID
        AND (p.ProjectName in (@parmProjects) OR p.ProjectName is null)
    INNER JOIN tTimesheets ts
        ON p.ProjectID = ts.ProjectID
    INNER JOIN tUsers u
        ON ts.CreatedBy = u.id
        AND
        (u.Name in (@parmUser) OR u.Name is null)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (tExpenses e
        INNER JOIN tExpenseType
            ON e.CategoryId = et.Id
       ) ON ts.CreatedBy = e.CreatedBy
           AND CAST(ts.ActivityDate AS date) = CAST(e.ExpenseDate AS DateTime)
           AND ts.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
)
  ON CAST(ts.ActivityDate AS date) = CAST(d.Date AS date)
   
WHERE        
(d.MonthNameYear in (@parmDate) OR d.MonthNameYear is null)

GROUP BY 
         u.Name,
         u.id,
         d.Date,
         d.MonthNameYear,
         p.ProjectName,
         p.ProjectID,
         e.ExpenseID,
         c.ClientName

ORDER BY d.Date;
```

An alternative is to place all the other joins in a derived table or CTE. This can sometimes be easier to write.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Wish I could buy you a beer. I have taken  your suggestions and brought them all into the final query, the OR was a stupid thing I was doing which is not required and deleted now, thanks!